# How to make css style on Google custom search engine

Tags: css, google-custom-search

How to style  Google custom search engine using css

Help me,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code you can share? What have you tried?

Comment: I try it myself.. Below are the answer **Give comments** if this code works well

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div class="messagepop pop">  
    <script>    //Google Custom Search Engine Code 
    </script> 
    <gcse:search> </gcse:search> 
    </div>




    .messagepop input{
    border: none; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    outline:0; 
    height:55px; 
   padding: 5px;
    }



    .messagepop input{box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34),
    -15px -14px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
    18px -55px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255,1),
    33px -6px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); }
    .messagepop input:last-child{ background: #32c77f; 
    line-height: 50px;     height: 35px; width: 80px; margin-top: 28px; }
```